# How to adjust my bass guitar bridge

Tags: bass-guitar, bridge

I’m trying to adjust my bass guitar bridge but my bridge is quite different compared to the bridges in online tutorials. I tried to find the name of my bridge but I can’t seem to find it.

[image]

If anyone can tell me the name and how to adjust the saddle height and the intonation it would be appreciated.

Comment: Bridge height should be adjustable by the grub screws in the bridge riders. I cannot tell from this image if there is any way of adjusting the position of the riders. Maybe you can include a picture without strings?

Comment: I’ve never seen this kind of bridge before. Good question!!

Comment: What is the brand and model of the bass? Can you provide a full pic?

Comment: I believe the intonation screws may have been removed. Are there holes in the back of the bridge by where the ball ends go?

Comment: No, there are no holes on where the ball ends is. What is a riders? I'm sorry I'm not native in English and quite new to bass guitar parts. I will post additional pictures when I get home.

Answer (score 2):

Adjusting the saddle height is easy - just use an Allen key (hex key) on either side of the string to raise/lower.

The intonation is a little unusual, in that there is no screw to move the saddle back or forth. But - with the string loosened, it will slide back or forth easily, and stay in that position once the string is back under tension.

Bit of a pain, as you'll have to guess where it'll end up while the string is tuned, loosen it, slide the saddle to where you guess, tune up again, check against the 12th fret, and keep doing that until you're happy that it's in the correct place. Once done, though, it'll stay there until the string gets changed, and shouldn't need moving even when that happens, if the same gauge is used. Worth double checking though...

If it was my bass, I'd be swapping that bridge for a more comprehensive and easier to use bridge, which shouldn't break the bank, and be far less frustrating to set up.

Comment: If they really are free-to-slide as they look, you'll need to repeat the process every time you change strings - they look like they'll just fall out without a string to keep them in place.  Weird setup.

Comment: @Tetsujin - good incentive to keep strings on a long time! Or mark them with a blob of something...

Comment: The fact that the saddle screws are diagonal and not side by side is also very strange.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - given that there's more meat centrally, it's a mystery. Although when it's all tight, it shouldn't matter. I'd still be sourcing a new bridge though.

Comment: I wonder if the intonation adjustment screws weren’t removed at some point. Another photo angle would confirm this or not. I think I can make out a hole below the ball end of the G string and in the saddle itself…

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - the only place it could be is central. I don't think there's enough meat there, but your eyesight must  be better than mine.

Comment: @Tim Most intonation adjustment screws are offset from center. If they weren’t they would interfere with the path of the string. Zoom as much as you can and look just below the G string ball end on the saddle side. There’s a little reflection that looks like the bottom of a hole.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - I can see *something* there, but *nothing* in line for the other three, which are possibly clearer to see. Strange.

Comment: @john I found out that you can adjust the height by tightening one of the screw on either side. The front one raise the bridge and it does the job, but the back screw lowers it very little almost unnoticeable. Buying a new bridge seems like the better choice for future use.

Comment: @jitapdarmawan - whichever you adjust, it makes sense to keep the saddle horizontal, level with the body of the bass, not sloping to either side of the string. That adjustment won't help *intonation* though. You'll find the back screw will adjust the height of the saddle, thus string, it's just that it's not through as far, maybe. Once you've slid the individual saddles into their correct places, you won't need to touch them again. See my answer.